# Powershell - How to exclude a sub property

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I am using Resource Graph to get all change records. All change records has "Changes" property and it has sub columns too. I want to exclude "properties.provisioningState" across all records.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6KOx.png)

Tried -ExcludeProperty but didn't work

Comment: In the pic you're attempting to exclude changecategory

Comment: second line is correct one.